# NFS server for Windows

Tags: windows

Since sharing files over SMB can be a little complex in Windows (please don't derail the post into discussing that), is there an easy way to share some files over NFS?

Answer (score 2):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/products/community#) is easy to install on Windows, and it is accessible via NFS.

NFS is disabled by default, so you have to activate it.

Only files that you have imported into Alfresco will be accessible (so it is not like your filesystem will be accessible).

Free, open source.

I hope there are more direct solutions, though.

Comment: It's not something that can be called a simple small NFS server. Solved it by bying a NAS :)

Comment: @SmitJohnth: *"Buy a NAS!"* is NOT a software recommendation :-) By the way, Alfresco is actually easy to install.

Comment: I'm not recommending it, I just said that it was easier for me to buy a NAS (I had a lack of free space too). It's install file is 600 Mb big which is not what I meant under "small easy server".